# How can write JavaScript code without jQuery by using bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I use this code for (bootstrap 5) without jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   setInterval(function(){
       var attend = jQuery('#pills-profile').hasClass('active');
       if(attend == true){
             jQuery('#id2').show();
             jQuery('#id1').hide();
         }else{
             jQuery('#id2').hide();
             jQuery('#id1').show();
         }
     }, 1000)
   });
```

Comment: No, you can't, you must rewrite it

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery, you can try to replace it by pure javascript function. You can find out more at https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const first = document.getElementById("id1");
  const second = document.getElementById("id2");
  const attend = document.getElementById("pills-profile");
  setInterval(function () {
    if (attend.classList.contains("active")) {
      second.style.display = "block";
      first.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      second.style.display = "none";
      first.style.display = "block";
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```